# What are the most effective market variables to measure liquidity/illiquidity in the market?

Tags: market-data, macro-economics, macro

I'm trying to find/create a variable that measures liquidity in financial markets in order to assess, for instance whether credit conditions tightened? Does anyone know any relevant literature concerning this subject?

Answer (score 1):

There are many different options. The Fed has a Senior Loan office survey of whether credit conditions have tightened or loosened. Macroeconomic forecasters often use this as part of U.S. GDP forecasting models. Other market-based variables, such as VIX and the spread between various bonds, to get a sense of financial conditions.

There are also some financial conditions indices out there. The Chicago Fed and Bloomberg both come to mind. Doesn't really make sense to re-invent the wheel, but if you need a longer history you can look at their methodology to get a sense of what they're doing.

Comment: Thanks a lot John! That's exactly the point, I am trying to get data since 1980 thus I'll take a look on those variables you've just mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Turnover ratio (TR) is one of the variables used. 
$TR_t=\frac{Total_. shares_. traded_. at_. time_. t}{Market_. capitalisation}$. This variable indicates the number of shares traded in a day. Liquidity is a tricky area and you will find various measures in various papers according the authors preference. I do not recommend directly using volume or market cap. These variables does not give relative comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Turnover ratio does not quite cut it because high liquidity is not the same as high trading activity. A nicer definition is how sensitive is the price to a given volume that is bid or offered. For that, check out [this paper.](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~lpederse/papers/liquidity_risk.pdf)